# List files in a specific format in bash

Tags: bash

I have a bunch of files that look like this:

```
file1.txt
file1.log
file2.txt
file2.log
file3.txt
file4.log
.
.
.
filen.txt
filen.log
```

I want to store them in a variable like this:

`./file1.,./file2.,./filen.,./stable.file.`

How can I do this? Please note that `stable.file.`  is a fixed string.

Thanks so much

Comment: `1., ./file2.,./f` So a space after comma or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something along:

```
printf "./%s\n" file*.txt stable.file. | sed 's/txt$//' | paste -sd,
```